# Add Rows dynamicaly on Ionic 2 using typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I want to click on a button that when clicked a row is inserted:

```
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col>
        1 of 2
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        2 of 2
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
  <button (click)="addrow"></button>
```

On a typescript side:

```
addrow(){
//code
}
```

Do you know any example using ionic 2 and typescript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an array to add rows dynamically. Please take a look at [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/AMWpHD5ZkIGXbufRlMTJ?p=info). Please notice that in the plunker I also use a `maxQuantity` property to disable the button (and avoid new rows to be added to the grid).

The view:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Ionic Demo</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>

  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row *ngFor="let row of rows">
      <ion-col>
        {{ row?.firstCol }}
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        {{ row?.secondCol }}
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
  <button ion-button [disabled]="rows?.length === maxQuantity" (click)="addrow()">Add a row</button>

</ion-content>
```

The component:

```
@Component({...})
export class HomePage {

  public rows: Array<{ firstCol: string, secondCol: string }> = [];
  private maxQuantity: number = 5;

  constructor() {}

  public addrow(): void {
    this.rows.push({ firstCol: '1 of 2', secondCol: '2 of 2' });
  }
}
```